# Wicket handle javascript URL change

Tags: java, html, wicket, wicket-6

I've got a page with a geographic map, mounted on `'/map/#{zoom}/#{lat}/#{lon}'`. The map is visible at `'/map/'` but at `'/map/z/x/y'` as well, centered at a different location. If not all of `zoom`, `lat` and `lon` are set, it shows the map at the default location.

When the map is panned, the current URL is updated with javascript: `history.replaceState({}, "", "/map/z/x/y")`

However when the map is accessed at '/map' all wicket generated URLs are relative to `'/map'`, for instance the homepage refers to `'..'`. But after panning, the relative url for the homepage is incorrect and actually points to `/map/z/x`, which shows the map again.

Is there a way to force Wicket to generate absolute urls, or is there a way to inform Wicket that the current url has changed?

**Edit:**
The issue also occurs in a different way. I've got a list of predefined overview, defined by their `/z/x/y` coordinates. When `z` is equal the created link is relative to `z`. However when the zoom changed, the new `z` value is incorrect for the linked overview.

#### Example:

I've got two predefined overviews: `A = 10/33/44` and `B = 10/66/77`. When `A` is clicked, the URL of the link of `B` is changed to `../../66/77`. When the map is panned and zoomed the (browser)URL changes to `4/12/3`. When the link to `B` is clicked the resulting URL is `4/66/77`

Comment: Out of curiosity - why you aren't using query parameters instead?

Comment: Mainly for aesthetics, this url may be published somewhere. However your question does make sense. I believe that using query parameters would avoid the issue i'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to update the url from the beginning!

In the page's constructor if there is no value for some of the parameters then set the default one:

```
public MapPage(PageParameters params) {
  super(params); // this is important! 

  String lon = params.get("lon").toString();
  if (lon == null) params.set("lon", DEFAULT_LON);
  // same for lan and zoom
}
```

This way Wicket will use the defaults when creating any links, and actually will redirect to `/map/x/y/z`.